# Save HTML formatted data to post meta using add_post_meta()

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

```
   Array
(
    [post] => Array
        (
            [jw_objective] => Exposure to e<b>nd to end development</b> of various applications; right from requirement analysis to system study, designing, coding, testing, de-bugging, <i>documentation and i</i>mplementation. Adept in <u>handling the design and coding functions</u>
            [postid] => 363
            [jw_fullname] => Pradeep
            [jw_email] => pradeepsk88@gmail.com
            [jw_phone] => 9952149811
            [jw_website] => www.por.com
            [jw_address1] => 83, VGP Nagar East
            [jw_address2] => T Nagar
            [jw_address3] => Chennai, India 605602
            [jw_title] => Senior Web Developer
            [jw_cname] => TPF Software Solutions
            [jw_startdate] => Dec 2010
            [jw_enddate] => Present
            [jw_desc] => This is my responsibilit<b>es in this job</b>
            [jw_qualifications] => Certiﬁed Public Acc<i>ountant (CPA)
                        Certiﬁed Management Accountant (CMA)
                        Certiﬁed Financial Manager (CFM)
                        Certiﬁed Fraud Examiner (CF</i>E)
                        Cer<b>tiﬁed Financial Planner (CFP)
                        Certiﬁed Internal Auditor (CIA)
                        Enrolled Agent (EA)
                        Certiﬁed Government Financial Manager (CGFM)
                                                                        </b>
            [jw_educname] => B.E
            [jw_eduiname] => Arunai College of Engineering
            [jw_edustartdate] => May 2005
            [jw_eduenddate] => May 2009
            [jw_edudesc] => This is a riduculous thing happen<b><i>ed in my life, </i></b>
            [jw_interest] => Th<i>ese are my interests</i>
            [jw_referance] => This Is my referance
        )

    )
```

This is the array I iterate through, and add it to the `wp_postmeta` through the following foreach loop

```
foreach ($_POST AS $key => $value) {
    add_post_meta($pid, $key, $value, true);
}
```

The information is posted from a custom form.

The problem I have is the HTML tags like `<b>` and `<i>` are automatically stripped off when entering the database. The HTML is generated from a jquery wysiwyg editor

But the information is saved successfully. Is there any way to save postmeta with the HTML tags?

Answer (score 2):

Is it that your tags are being stripped, or that you aren't preparing them prior to displaying them. Try wrapping your output:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', get_post_meta($post->ID, '_custom_field_name', true));
```

Answer (score 0):

On Update Use `addslashes();` And On Print Use `stripslashes();`

Comment: Some explanation with examples would be great.